# Unexpected keyword 'export' error in ReactNative - yarn workspace

Tags: react-native, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to set up a react native project inside a yarn workspace and got Android running by preceding all `node_modules` references in `.gradle` files with `../` to reference `node_modules` in the workspace folder.

But that didn't work in iOS and later I heard it's better to do the `nohoist` and I tried adding the following in my react native project `package.json

```
  private: true,
  "workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "**"
    ]
  }
```

Or

```
  private: true,
  "workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "react-native",
      "react-native/**",
      "react",
      "react/**"
    ]
  }
```

But in both case, I'm getting the following error,

> Unhandled JS exception: Unexpected keyword 'export'

[image]

More details: Fresh project created with `react-native init`

```
react-native: 0.63.4
react: 16.13.1
```